# The memory consumption of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

There is some code, I'm wondering, does memory economy occur in this case?

```
var Person = {
  getName: function(){
    return this.name;
  },
  bigMethod: function(){
    // here some large code 
  }
};

var createPerson = function(obj){
  var person = {};      
  person.getName = function(){
    return Person.getName.call(obj); 
  };
  person.bigMethod =function(){
    return Person.bigMethod.call(obj);
  };
  return person;
}

var persons = [];

for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++){
  persons.push(createPerson({name:'Gregory'}));
}
```

or in principle, I can do so:

```
var createPerson = function(obj){
    var person = {};      
    person.getName = function(){
      return obj.name; 
    };
    person.bigMethod = function(){
      // here some large code 
    };
    return person;
}

var persons = [];

for (var i =0; i < 1000; i++){
  persons.push(createPerson({name:'Gregory'}));
}
```

In the first case I moved the implementation of some hypothetical method with a long code in a separate Person object and I call it from createPerson.
And in the second case I just create an object with the necessary methods and return the object.

Comment: In both cases you're creating unnecessary new functions every time you construct a new object.  You could just use your `Person` object as the prototype in [`Object.create(Person)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Why don't you use prototype based "classes"? There you only declare functions once. In both your examples you're creating new functions for each person.

Comment: Yes, I know about the prototype, but in my case I create objects with data encapsulation, which can not be done through prototypes or can I?

Comment: and in principle, there should be memory savings?

Comment: What does "memory economy occurring" mean?

Comment: Saving memory ))

Comment: sorry for my bad English ;)

Comment: The footprint is going to be exponentially lower if you have N number of objects referencing 2 functions and not N number of objects referencing N*2 functions.

Comment: Why exactly do need such absolute "encapsulation"? Do you *really* have an iron clad reason for "needing" this?

Comment: It is possible that someday it will be necessary and it is necessary to know how to do this

Comment: 2Emissary 
I meant methods with large code. This is just an example.

Comment: Until that day comes, don't worry about it and use prototypes…

Comment: @Cfon Yes, this is a proper way to encapsulate the data objects, no this is not memory friendly (but doesn't really matter for a mere 1000 objects), and no it makes absolutely no difference whether you put the implementation in a separate object or in the closures directly.

Comment: Thank you all ;)